# Spring MVC 4.0 - Hibernate OpenSessionViewFilter in WebConfig

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Basically, how can I do this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

in `WebInitializer`?

Beacuse if a write:

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { 
        new SpringSecurityFilterChain(), new OpenSessionViewFilter()    
    };
}
```

it doesn't take any effect.

I think the url-pattern is missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what we have done

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer 
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) 
        throws ServletException {
      servletContext
        .addFilter("securityFilter", 
                   new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

       //add other filters like this
     super.onStartup(servletContext);
  }
}
```